# Use LinkedIn API with Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, linkedin-api

I'm using the API from the following site in order to connect to LinkedIn:

http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth/comments/page/2/

But i'm trying to find a guide to learn how to get the list of contacts using xcode but couldn't find anything...

Can anyone direct me to anything?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Connections API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api) from LinkedIn's Docs.

> The Connections API returns a list of 1st degree connections for a user who has granted access to his/her account. You can control the fields you want to have returned and the number of connections returned for each call.